# Pandas style function to highlight specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I have been trying to write a function to use with pandas [`style`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html). I want to highlight specific columns that I specify in the arguments. This is not very elegant, but for example:

```
data =  pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=list('ABC'))

def highlight_cols(df, cols, colcolor = 'gray'):
    for col in cols:
        for dfcol in df.columns:
            if col == cols:
                color = colcolor
    return ['background-color: %s' % color]*df.shape[0]
```

then call with:

```
data.style.apply(highlight_cols(cols=['B','C']))
```

I get an error:
`'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'`

I think I fundamentally don't quite understand how the styler calls and `apply`ies the function.

Answer (score 53):

I think you can use [Slicing in `Styles`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html#Finer-Control:-Slicing) for select columns `B` and `C` and then `Styler.applymap` for elementwise styles.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data =  pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=list('ABC'))
#print (data)

def highlight_cols(s):
    color = 'grey'
    return 'background-color: %s' % color

data.style.applymap(highlight_cols, subset=pd.IndexSlice[:, ['B', 'C']])
```

[image: pic]

If you want more colors or be more flexible, use `Styler.apply(func, axis=None)`, the function must return a `DataFrame` with the same index and column labels:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data =  pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=list('ABC'))
#print (data)

def highlight_cols(x):
    #copy df to new - original data are not changed
    df = x.copy()
    #select all values to default value - red color
    df.loc[:,:] = 'background-color: red'
    #overwrite values grey color
    df[['B','C']] = 'background-color: grey'
    #return color df
    return df    

data.style.apply(highlight_cols, axis=None)
```

[image: pic1]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I want to return value as zero after styling. is it possible? I am encountering with Styler error.,

Comment: I have tried like returning return 'background-color: %s; data:0;' % color 

return 'background-color: %s; content:0;' % color

Comment: @CSMaverick - Sorry, I am a bit confused, is possible create new question? Be free use this answer for it.

Comment: Is there a way to count the number of rows that have been highlighted?

Comment: @MOA - here it depends of selected columns, e.g. cout = df[['B','C']].size should working

Comment: @jezrael, How about in the case where not all rows have been highlighted?

Comment: @MOA - I think the best is create question, it depends of your code.

Comment: @jezrael In your first code block, I tried changing it to `def highlight_cols(color)` so I could input any color that I need. But then, `data.style.applymap(highlight_cols, subset=pd.IndexSlice[:, ['B', 'C']])` didn't work any more. Could you please help? Thanks!

Comment: One can use 'background-color: grey' to indicate no change

Answer (score 26):

You can do it bit more dynamically:

```
data =  pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=list('ABC'))

# dictionary of column colors
coldict = {'A':'grey', 'C':'yellow'}

def highlight_cols(s, coldict):
    if s.name in coldict.keys():
        return ['background-color: {}'.format(coldict[s.name])] * len(s)
    return [''] * len(s)

data.style.apply(highlight_cols, coldict=coldict)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the method [`style.set_properties`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.set_properties.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [3, 4], 'C': [5, 6]})

df.style.set_properties(subset=['A', 'C'], **{'background-color': 'green'})
```

Result:

[image]