# Add style class to pandas DataFrame HTML

Tags: python, html, css, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a pandas DataFrame and I use `style.apply` to manipulate the styles:

```py
# sample code by jezrael from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41654949/pandas-style-function-to-highlight-specific-columns 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data =  pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=list('ABC'))
# print(data)

def highlight_cols(x):
    # copy df to new - original data are not changed
    df = x.copy()
    # select all values to default value - red color
    df.loc[:,:] = 'background-color: red'
    # overwrite values grey color
    df[['B','C']] = 'background-color: grey'
    # return color df
    return df    

data = data.style.apply(highlight_cols, axis=None)
```

This however produces a class in each of the `<td>` tag and then dynamically adds styling to each.

I want to add class `red` for the first case, and `grey` for the second, in terms of HTML (`<td class="red">content</td>`) for further processing in my own .css file. Is it possible directly with pandas? If not, are there any libraries that will let me manipulate the HTML contents of the pandas DataFrame?

Thanks in advance for any help.