# Pandas: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'style'

Tags: python, pandas, series, pandas-styles

I'm trying to color just a certain output, something like this

```
df['a'] = df['a'].fillna(df['b'].map(s)).style.applymap(lambda x: "background-color:yellow")
```

so I get the error

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'style'
```

How can I make it right and color only the output that comes out of this?

Comment: This might help,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41654949/pandas-style-function-to-highlight-specific-columns

Comment: Nope that's not what I'm looking for, this highlights whole columns which I don't need, I need to highlight the cells got printed by a certain code

Comment: Please elaborate your question more..by giving a dummy `df` example. Also `style` function applies on `DataFrame` and you are applying on `Series`.

Answer (score 9):

As someone called out, `style` formatter is for DataFrames and you are working with a Series. You can either preface the `.style` call with `.to_frame()`
e.g.

```py
df['a'] = df['a'].fillna(df['b'].map(s)).to_frame().style.applymap(lambda x: "background-color:yellow")
```

Or, less explicitly, to work with a DataFrame rather than Series wrap your column names in another set of brackets e.g. `df[['a']]` instead of `df['a']`