# How to color individual cells of a pandas data frame based on dictionary values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas df

```
      Player    Team     EPA
0   L.Jackson   BAL     0.33
1   P.Mahomes   KC      0.25
2   D.Brees     NO      0.24
3   M.Stafford  DET     0.21
4   D.Prescott  DAL     0.19
5   R.Tannehill TEN     0.18
```

That I want to style using the colors by applying the following dictionary values, where the keys match the `Team` field. I would also like to make the corresponding values of the `Player` field the same color.

```
COLORS = {'BAL':'#241773','DAL':'#B0B7BC','DET':'#046EB4',
          'KC':'#CA2430','NO':'#A08A58','TEN':'#4095D1'}
```

I tried looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41654949/pandas-style-function-to-highlight-specific-columns) and had no success with the following code

```
def highlight_cols(s, coldict):
    if qbs.Team in COLORS.keys():
        return ['background-color: {}'.format(COLORS[qbs.Team])] * len(s)
    return [''] * len(s)

qbs.style.apply(highlight_cols, coldict=COLORS)
```

I have been reading through the `DataFrame.style` [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html) and have been trying to figure out a way where I can color each `Team` value corresponding with the hexcode in the dictionary. In cells 5 and 6 of the notebook in the documentation, it shows how you can write a function and use `df.style.applymap()` to apply a function, but I'm not entirely sure how to go about this specific function. I tried using a `.loc` to no avail. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you just want the EPA column colored, if you want the entire row remove the `subset` argument from the last line.

```
def highlight_cols(s, coldict):
    return ['background-color: {}'.format(COLORS[v]) if v else '' for v in qbs.Team.isin(COLORS.keys())*qbs.Team.values]
    

qbs.style.apply(highlight_cols, coldict=COLORS, subset='EPA')
```