# assigning a color to a cell in a column if condition is met_python

Tags: python, styles, apply

I am trying to count the number of words in each row on a column using

```
df['new_column'] = df.column1.apply(lambda x: len(str(x).split(' ')))
```

This is creating a new column in my df with the number of words from column'column1'. I want to color the cells from 'column1' which, have less than 5 words. Is there a way I can do this with python applicable to all rows in the column 'column1'?

```
column 1
Camiseta Tecnica hombre barata
deportivas calcetin hombres running
Camiseta Tecnica mejores deportivas running Camiseta
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas style function to highlight specific columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41654949/pandas-style-function-to-highlight-specific-columns)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the pandas `Styler` doing the transformation within the color change function.

```
# color change func
def change_colour(x):
    return ['background-color: green' if len(x[0].split()) < 5 else '']

# pass in the series as a df using to_frame()
df['column1'].to_frame().style.apply(change_colour, axis=1)
```

Try this to export to excel:

```
df['column1'].to_frame().style.apply(change_colour,axis=1).
to_excel('test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html

Comment: It returns two errors:    
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' and AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'style'     I have tried before with .style and got the same error

Comment: can you post your df please?

Comment: I have updated in the description, it is just a column with many rows (I just passed 3 of them), on each row I have several words to count and highlight cells where less than 5 words are found

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot but still not working, I believe there's something wrong when printing to excel, like the code looks fine, also from the example provided above by Salma, the code has nothing wrong just that the color is not printed in excel, there's something Im missing here I guess

Comment: I didn't know you wanted to export to excel. I have tested the edit above and it now works