# Understand pandas' applymap argument

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-applymap

I'm trying to highlight specific columns in my dataframe using guideline from this post, https://stackoverflow.com/a/41655055/5158984.

My question is on the use of the `subset` argument. My guess is that it's part of the `**kwargs` argument. However, the official documentation from Pandas, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html, vaguely explains it.

So in general, how can I know which key words I can use whenever I see `**kwargs`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are confusing `pandas.DataFrame.applymap` and `df.style.applymap` (where df is an instance of pd.DataFrame), for which `subset` stands on its own and is not part of the `kwargs` arguments.

Here is one way to find out (in your terminal or a Jupyter notebook cell) what are the named parameters of this method (or any other Pandas method for that matter):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
help(df.style.applymap)

# Output

Help on method applymap in module pandas.io.formats.style:

applymap(func: 'Callable', subset: 'Subset | None' = None, **kwargs) 
-> 'Styler' method of pandas.io.formats.style.Styler instance
    Apply a CSS-styling function elementwise.
    
    Updates the HTML representation with the result.
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    func : function
        ``func`` should take a scalar and return a string.
    
    subset : label, array-like, IndexSlice, optional
        A valid 2d input to `DataFrame.loc[<subset>]`, or, in the case of a 1d input
        or single key, to `DataFrame.loc[:, <subset>]` where the columns are
        prioritised, to limit ``data`` to *before* applying the function.
    
    **kwargs : dict
        Pass along to ``func``. 
   ...
```