# style minimum value in row excluding some columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I have a dataframe with numerical data I want to highlight the two minimum values row-wise excluding one column (target). This is what I get so far, but stuck on excluding the mentioned column and so is highlighted too.

```py
np.random.seed(123)
rows = 5
cols= {'column_a': [np.random.randint(100) for _ in range(rows)],
       'column_b': [np.random.randint(100) for _ in range(rows)],
       'column_c': [np.random.randint(100) for _ in range(rows)],
       'target': [np.random.randint(100) for _ in range(rows)]}
data = pd.DataFrame(cols)

(data.style.highlight_min(props='background-color:lightgreen', axis=1) )
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas style function to highlight specific columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41654949/7758804)

Comment: `data.style.highlight_min(props='background-color:lightgreen', axis=1, subset=pd.IndexSlice[:, data.columns[:-1]])`